# Did liberalism in the USA degenerate into something more totalitarian than liberal?

Tags: united-states

I'm not US resident, so that's a real question rather than pre-election discussion.

Where I live liberalism never seriously changed meaning in public debate (yet) - it is still more or less faithul to the ideas of classical liberalism from XVIII and XIX century. As such it is an opposite of totalitarianism and socialism. (which doesn't necesarilly mean that liberals enjoy wide support).

Bits and pieces of news from the USA lead me to believe that US "liberals" abandoned the idea of maximization of personal liberties and minimization of the involvement of state in various areas of citzen's life (notably economic activities).
Is this a valid observation? Is this used in political debates to discredit "liberals" or did the public generally accept the new meaning of "liberalism"?

Comment: You should take into account that the term "liberalism" has different meaning in the USA than elsewhere in the world. In the USA they call "liberals" the LEFT politicians and movements, unlike other countries where "liberal" usually means a right-wing politician. This is very confusing to anybody who is not accustomed with the US politics.

Comment: left-wing, right-wing - this doesn't tell me much. Nazism is said to be right-wing, while communism left-wing, but from the point of view of classical liberals they are both totalitarian.

Comment: In US politics "liberal" generally means somebody or something our right-wing party doesn't like. Aside from that, **there is no ideological consistency to the term**. For example, forcing universal healthcare coverage via tax penalties to those without it started life as a right-wing idea to counter "liberal" ideas the other party had like true socalized medicine. However, once the other party took it up themselves, it became a "liberal" idea.

Comment: @T.E.D. well, in my country making entire medicine paid, optional and commercial would be considered a "liberal" idea.

Comment: @T.E.D. - it's simpler. If it's for bigger government control, it's "progrssive/liberal". So yes, to a "right wing" person - itself a misnomer even more egregious than "liberal", a tax on not insured is more a liberal idea than no tax, but a less liberal idea than Soviet style socialized "medicine" (having participated in the latter, I know a lot more about it than most people talking about it from both sides of the argument in the USA).

Comment: @DVK - Not really. That doesn't explain abortion policy, where "liberal" is for less government control, nor federal marriage policy where "liberal" is against government dictates to the states about which of their marriages will be recognized and against state restrictions on marriage. With work, and a bit of creative opposition definition, you can craft explanations for these, but that only reinforces the fact that all "liberal" really ends up meaning is "something/someone the right wing doesn't like".

Comment: @T.E.D. - Abortion is viewed as "murder" among most right wingers, rightly or wrongly. I don't think you can argue that less government control dedicated **to prevent murder** is against a right wing position. They are right wing, not Anarchists :) . As far as marriage, there's a small but severely growing movement on the right to get the marriage FULLY out of the government (or government out of the marriage). It shouldn't be something government decides on in the first place. Yes, there are certain things right wing would want to delegate to government. But VERY VERY few.

Comment: @DVK - Like I said, creative opposition defintion. If abortion is murder, then miscarriage (something most mothers of multiple children have experienced) is involutary manslaughter at least. A rather rediculous position, but that's where you have to go to pretend ideological consistency.

Comment: @T.E.D. - actually, miscarriage resulting from some actions of the mother (e.g. taking drugs) is, not an unreasonable position, from either left or right POV. OTOH, most miscarriages don't result from specific actions of a person that can be proven in a court of law.

Comment: @DVK - With these successive clarifications of clarifications IMHO you've proved my point. Personally **I believe in Occam's Razor**, and the simplest explanation that fits the observable behavior is that they make up the defition of "Liberal" to suit themselves.

Comment: @T.E.D.- logical fallacy there. You haven't given as single example of what a typical liberal policy that is for SMALLER government role (law enforcement and military not counting). The fact that some of right wing policy also includes increased government role compared to libertarian ones is not relevant to that. The important fact is the philosophy of "goverment==good" that Progressive movement held since Wilson's times, not specific minor quibbles on either side.

Comment: By the way, even on marriage you are wrong. The right as a whole doesn't want **bigger** government role. It doesn't want a CHANGED government role. Nobody on the right ever wanted a law that prohibits some Elvis impersonator to marry 2 same sex people (which would indeed be more government). They just don't want an extra law that gives preferential (married) treatment by the government to gay couples. Whether they are right or wrong is irrelevant, but they don't push for MORE government.

Comment: @T.E.D. ... IOW, if tomorrow people like me have their own way and marriage no longer gets ANY preferencial treatment from the government and is 100% given back to private contract between 2 people it was till 1600s, the right would not need or care about defense of marriage act or anything of the sort, despite the fact that it would also provide full equality to gays. And despite that fact (full eqaulity as a result), you'll not see a single influencial liberal advocating this libertarian solution for marriage equality.

Comment: @DVK - If my theory is correct, doing so would be impossible. Its like arguing against String Theory. There's no way to invalidate a theory when supporters get to redefine both the theory and the meaning of the evidence to suit themselves. Its what we call `Not Even Wrong`. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong )

Comment: @T.E.D. - very easy to invalidate. Show me one **major** policy by liberals as a wide class calling for lessening the role of government not involving law enforcement/war. TRUE lessening, not merely tweaking a rule (e.g. "no government preferencial treatment to heterosexual married couples" is lessening). As in, supporting a libertarian solution to a problem, NOT merely rejecting a conservative one that just happens to be also increasing govenrment. (war on drugs doesn't count since both sides happily support it *en masse*). Resulting in 1 less law and several less govt. employees/spending.

Comment: @DVK ... I could show several, but then you'd get to argue (as you've done above) those don't fit because of X,Y,Z. Which of course may not be true because of Q,R,S, but then why am I purposely ignoring I,J, and K, and next thing you know we have 20 comments back and forth proving nothing. Frankly, that's not a discussion I even care about. It's not even wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Anixx's comment is quite right: in America "liberal" means "center-left".

According to the Encyclopedia Britannica, "In the United States liberalism is associated with the welfare-state policies of the New Deal program of the Democratic administration of Pres. Franklin D. Roosevelt, whereas in Europe it is more commonly associated with a commitment to limited government and laissez-faire economic policies."

But for the rest of the world, a "(Classical-type) liberal" refers to what Americans call a "(right-wing) libertarian" (more commonly just *libertarian*).

Recent right-wing rhetoric has castigated any form of government and/or left-wing ideas as "totalitarian" and "socialistic". I won't comment on the validity of these claims, but I suspect they would cause confusion for...well, everyone.

Comment: Could you clarify where in the world liberal = right-leaning libertarian? I ask as being in Canada, liberal usually refers to the centre-left of the political spectrum (although not the American version, which is a tad skewed). And I was always given the impression that Englands version is quite similar to ours as well.

Comment: @canadiancreed: I updated my post, since the UK Liberal party's ideology has changed since I studied it (i.e., since the 19th century!). What I mean is "Classical liberalism" is, in America, called "Libertarianism"; like Japan's Liberal Democratic party or Neoliberalism...

Comment: Actually, in the 18th and 19th Centuries the term generally indicated a desire to open up the voting franchise, and make representative bodies soverign.